# How to Open Windows Store with my all apps

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to add a menu in my app that is, "More Apps". In that menu I want to open the store with my all apps. How to do that ?

[basically my app is in Windows 8.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Windows 8.1 update the Package Name of Windows Store App is changed to `ms-windows-store` so, to get the list of any publisher we have to use the below code.

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SearchForAnApp()
{
 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:publisher=company-name"));
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Function to Search for an App by publisher in Windows Phone Store using URI Scheme in Windows Phone 8 using C#.

private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SearchForAnApp()
{
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("zune:search?publisher=Abundantcode"));
}
```